# Reversing the order of duplicated sections in a vector

Tags: r

Consider the following pre-sorted vector `x`.

```
x <- c(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8)
```

`order()` shows us the order of the vector.

```
( o <- order(x) )
# [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Now suppose I want to reverse the order of only the duplicated/repeated values of `x`, meaning I want to reverse just the `2 3 4` and `7 8 9` sections of `o` because those are the values repeated in `x`. Then, **the desired result would be**

```
[1]  1  4  3  2  5  6  9  8  7 10
```

What is the best way to do that?  Right now I've got the following

```
w <- which(duplicated(x) | duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE))
o[w] <- rev(o[w])
```

But that does not give the correct answer here.

```
o
# [1]  1  9  8  7  5  6  4  3  2 10
```

PS - I am using this to reverse the column order of duplicated column names.

Comment: Is the vector `x` assumed to be always ordered to begin with or would a solution have to generalize for unordered `x`s? For instance, what is your desired result for `x <- c(1,3,5,2,7,2,7,2,7,8)`?

Comment: round of golf anyone? `rev(order(-x))`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `data.table v1.9.6`:

```
require(data.table)
as.data.table(x)[, .(id = rev(.I)), by=x]
#     x id
#  1: 1  1
#  2: 2  4
#  3: 2  3
#  4: 2  2
#  5: 3  5
#  6: 5  6
#  7: 7  9
#  8: 7  8
#  9: 7  7
# 10: 8 10
```

---

Alternatively, you can do:

```
order(x + sort(runif(length(x)), dec=TRUE))
#  [1]  1  4  3  2  5  6  9  8  7 10
```

(not entirely sure if there are cases where this could break)

Comment: How on earth did you come up with that `runif()` one?  That's impressive.

Comment: The `runif()` one is a really impressive quick and dirty trick.

Comment: The `runif` one will work if you have an integer-valued vector (as Richard does in the problem), but I guess it could misorder the vector if the gaps between elements were smaller than 1.

Comment: @josilber I think `order( rank(x) + sort(runif(length(x)), dec = TRUE))` should work for the general case..?

Comment: @Frank yeah, I think that should do it for the general case.

Answer (score 12):

A base R 1-liner would be using `ave` to group the ordering by unique values in the original vector, applying `rev` to reverse the ordering for each group:

```
ave(order(x), x, FUN=rev)
# [1]  1  4  3  2  5  6  9  8  7 10
```